# Combining Data from one object array to another object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm looking to combine an array returned from my local Database with dummy data to be sent to the frontend.

I have the two arrays of objects, Users come directly from my mongo database and before I send the result to the frontend, I would like to add the dummy data to the user object array. Now the Users list is a lot larger than my dummy data and thus I would like to loop through my user data and append the dummyData to every user object and once I reach the end of my dummyData, it should just start from the top again.

```
let users = [
      { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" },
      { name: "Peter", lastName: "Pumpkin" },
      {name: "John", lastName: "Snow"},
      {name: "Jack", lastName: "Stevens"}

    ];
let dummyData = [
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Agent)",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
        company: "Some Company"
      },
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(James Bond)",
        callStatus: "Pending Call",
        orderStatus: "No Order Placed",
        consultant: "Sally Sue",
        company: "Super Sonic & Co"
      },
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Peter Griffin))",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Jenny Oldstone",
        company: "Witcher School"
      }
    ];
```

The desired end result should be:

```
users[
       {name: "John", 
        lastName: "Henry",
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Agent)",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
        company: "Some Company" 
     }]
```

I think I can achieve this via a forloop, but I've never looped through objects before.

Comment: Give it a shot then

Comment: what the logic for add this user to which dummydata ??

Answer (score 1):

```
let k = 0;
users.forEach((item,i)=> {
 k = k === dummyData.length ? 0 : k;
 users[i] =  {...users[i],...dummyData[k]};
 k++;
});
console.log(users)
```

Try this -

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var user0 = { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" };

var data0 = {
  callTime: "Call Now",
  userType: "End User(Agent)",
  callStatus: "Called",
  orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
  consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
  company: "Some Company"
};

var sum0 =  Object.assign(user0, data0);

console.log(sum0);
```

Full example:

```js
let users = [
      { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" },
      { name: "Peter", lastName: "Pumpkin" },
      {name: "John", lastName: "Snow"},
      {name: "Jack", lastName: "Stevens"}

    ];
let dummyData = [
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Agent)",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
        company: "Some Company"
      },
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(James Bond)",
        callStatus: "Pending Call",
        orderStatus: "No Order Placed",
        consultant: "Sally Sue",
        company: "Super Sonic & Co"
      },
      {
        callTime: "Call Now",
        userType: "End User(Peter Griffin))",
        callStatus: "Called",
        orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
        consultant: "Jenny Oldstone",
        company: "Witcher School"
      }
    ];
    
users2 = users.map((user, i) => {
  Object.assign(user, dummyData[i]);
});

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { 
    users[i] = {...users[i], ...dummyData[i]}
}
```

Comment: dummyData looks to be shorter than users, use remainder to cycle dummyData index. `...dummyData[i % dummyData.length]`

Comment: @pilchard that's a valid point, but JS will simply ignore spread operator when used with `null` or `undefined`

Comment: Unless the OP is looking to generate dummy data for all users with limited dummyData templates.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.reduce` seems like a more readable approach.

```js
const output = users.reduce((acc, user, index) => [...acc, { ...user, ...data[index] } ], [])
```

Although it's not necessary, you might want to verify there absolutely is a corresponding data index to each user object:

```js
const output = users.reduce((acc, user, index) => data[index]
  ? [...acc, { ...user, ...data[index] } ]
  : [...acc, user ], [])
```

I would also encourage you, to provide some sort of identifier to each data/user object, that way you wouldn't have to rely on their order.

```js
const output = users.reduce((acc, user) => [...acc, {
  ...user,
  ...(data.find(dUser => dUser.id === user.id) || {})
}], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple reduce function should do the trick here. In fact, I did some testing, and it appears you don't even need to do any extra checks for whether `dummyData[i]` exists. An index being undefined doesn't throw an error and doesn't break the functionality at all. Those indexes merely get skipped, which would be the desired functionality anyway if there were ever a mismatch in the number of elements, I would presume.

If you are wanting to overwrite the `users` array of objects with the new array, this should do exactly what you are looking for:

```js
users = users.reduce((a,c,i) => [...a, {...c, ...dummyData[i]}], []);
```

Here it is in action:

```js
let users = [{ name: "John", lastName: "Henry" }, { name: "Peter", lastName: "Pumpkin" }, { name: "John", lastName: "Snow" }, { name: "Jack", lastName: "Stevens" }];
let dummyData = [{ callTime: "Call Now", userType: "End User(Agent)", callStatus: "Called", orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)", consultant: "Bennie Hennie", company: "Some Company" }, { callTime: "Call Now", userType: "End User(James Bond)", callStatus: "Pending Call", orderStatus: "No Order Placed", consultant: "Sally Sue", company: "Super Sonic & Co" }, { callTime: "Call Now", userType: "End User(Peter Griffin))", callStatus: "Called", orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)", consultant: "Jenny Oldstone", company: "Witcher School" }];

users = users.reduce((a,c,i) => [...a, {...c, ...dummyData[i]}], []);

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a for-loop and treat the object as an array.

```js
var user0 = { name: "John", lastName: "Henry" };

var data0 = {
  callTime: "Call Now",
  userType: "End User(Agent)",
  callStatus: "Called",
  orderStatus: "Order Placed(1)",
  consultant: "Bennie Hennie",
  company: "Some Company"
};

for(d in data0){
  user0[d] = data0[d];
}

console.log(user0);
```